# defining a fuction using the for loop / Python

Tags: python, function, loops, func

I need to define a function using the *for loop*. it's purpose is to check whether a letter included in *secret_word* is already included in the *old_letters_guessed* list. if it is, the function returns True. else, False. This is what I wrote thus far:

```
def check_win(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
   for letter in old_letters_guessed or secret_word:
    if (secret_word.count(letter) > old_letters_guessed.count(letter)) and (old_letters_guessed.count(letter) == 0) or (secret_word.count(letter) > 0) and (old_letters_guessed.count(letter) == 0):
     return False
    else:
     return True
```

**It works fine in these scenarios:**

```
check_win('typewriter',['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'])

True

check_win('typewriter',[])

False

check_win('',['q'])

True
```

**but in here, instead of returning False, its returning True:**

```
check_win('typewriter',['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o'])

True
```

I've tried altering it many times without succeess and would appreciate your help.

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: `old_letters_guessed or secret_word` doesn't do what you seem to expect.  It *picks one of the objects* - the leftmost one that is nonempty.  It doesn't combine the two, which I think is what you need.  You then have the problem that you're returning either True or False on the first iteration of the loop; no further letters have any effect on the answer.

Comment: `if something:` `return False` `else:` `return True`  can be simplified as `return not something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
def check_win(word, guessed):
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in guessed:
            return False
    return True

print(check_win('typewriter', ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'])) # True
print(check_win('typewriter', [])) # False
print(check_win('', ['q'])) # True
print(check_win('typewriter', ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o'])) # False
```

What is happening in your code is it is returning something in the first iteration, rendering the for loop useless.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the function:

- use in-operator instead of .count
- use yield to "collect" returns
  for great explanation see:  [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

##### try it out:

```
def check_win(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
    for letter in old_letters_guessed:
        yield letter in secret_word     # same as: if letter in secret_word: yield True, else: yield False

secret = "typewriter"
old = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p']
```

##### calling this "yielding-function" does not work the way functions usually do, because its a generator

```
print(check_win(secret,old))
returns <generator object check_win at 0x0000020BFF8480B0>
```

##### instantiate generator object:

```
mygenerator = check_win(secret,old)
n = 0
for i in mygenerator:
    print(f"{old[n]} is in {secret}: {i}")
    n += 1
returns:
>>> q is in typewriter: False
>>> w is in typewriter: True
>>> e is in typewriter: True
>>> r is in typewriter: True
>>> t is in typewriter: True
>>> y is in typewriter: True
>>> u is in typewriter: False
>>> i is in typewriter: True
>>> o is in typewriter: False
>>> p is in typewriter: True
```

Once this works properly, you can think of ways to count the matches. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! learned a lot from this comment